# Can an FAA-certified pilot rent/fly a GA aircraft in England?

Tags: easa-regulations, eu, rental

I am a U.S. certificated pilot in the U.S.A. I have about 1200 hrs flying mostly general aviation.

I will be traveling to England with family in March 2019 for a personal vacation. I would like to know if anyone on StackExchange has rented an airplane in Englad before and what their experience in doing this was.

In addition, it looks like it would be pretty easy to qualify for an EASA license in England. Any advice/insight on how to go about this?

Comment: Thanks for updating the subject line..

Comment: You might get an answer from this UK forum:  https://forums.flyer.co.uk/viewforum.php?f=1

Comment: @BradWalker You're welcome. :) Good question, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

You can rent a G-registration aircraft but your license will be treated as a UK private pilot ticket with day VFR privileges without any additional paperwork so long as you stay in UK airspace. There is a basic requirement to file one form, and you must get a signoff on simple theoretical knowledge, but that is it for now. See this [CAA Information Notice](http://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/InformationNotice2017029.pdf) for additional details.

Comment: I'm not challenging your answer, but a link to the CAA regulations or another source would be great.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the information you requested.